# Mock HTTP server that performs content negotiation

Tags: python, unit-testing, http, testing, mocking

I normally use Python's `http.server` to mock an HTTP server but this time I need the server to perform content negotiation.

I just need it to return an error if it cannot match the Accept header. Python's server ignores the header.

The way to run the server could be in a thread or in a separate process such as by running `python -m http.server`.

Answer (score 1):

You can, still using `http.server`, but using a custom handler...

```
class MockHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'

    def do_GET(self):
        if 'text/html' not in self.headers['Accept']:
            self.send_response(406)
        else:
            self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'some data')

class ThreadedHTTPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, http.server.HTTPServer):
    pass

server_address = ('localhost', 8888)
server = ThreadedHTTPServer(server_address, MockHandler)
server.daemon_threads = True
thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
```

(Note: it's a HTTP 1.1 server, since most servers are these days, and it's thread/multiple request-safe, but you can probably simplify if you would like...)

A full example in a small test-suite-of-one along with an example "production" function that you might want to test is below.

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import threading
import unittest
import urllib.request


def example_production_function(accept_header):
    req = urllib.request.Request('http://localhost:8888', headers={'Accept': accept_header});
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        return 'Allowed'
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        return 'Not allowed'


class TestServer(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):

        class MockHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
            protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'

            def do_GET(self):
                if 'text/html' not in self.headers['Accept']:
                    self.send_response(406)
                else:
                    self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(b'some data')

        class ThreadedHTTPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, http.server.HTTPServer):
            pass

        server_address = ('localhost', 8888)
        server = ThreadedHTTPServer(server_address, MockHandler)
        server.daemon_threads = True
        thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

        result = example_production_function('text/html')
        self.assertEqual(result, 'Allowed')

        result = example_production_function('application/json')
        self.assertEqual(result, 'Not allowed')

        server.shutdown()
        server.server_close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can implement what I need. The question is for a server which already implements content negotiation. Nevertheless, your example is quite nice!

Comment: @Javier Ah maybe I misunderstand... can you post in the question showing how you would like the mock server to be used?

Comment: Added an example. `http.server` detects the content type of files, if it performed negotiation, it would be enough.

Comment: @Javier I'm even more confused, since my example does run a server in a separate thread. Can you show both the production code and the test code that you would like this mock server to be used with?

Comment: It's very simple. I want a server to be used for testing that performs content negotiation automatically. I don't want to implement the content negotiation myself. The MIME type of the files to serve should be guessed from the extension.

Comment: @Javier How can the mock server know what to accept or what to reject if you don't implement it yourself? I suspect there is some context here I'm missing...

Comment: Lets say a file has MIME type `image/png`. If the Accept header is `*/*`, it should return the file. If it is `image/*`, it should return the file. If it is `text/*`, it should fail with 406. That is part of the protocol, not business logic.

Comment: @Javier Ah... is this mock server to serve files from the local filesystem?

Comment: That feature is enough. If it's more versatile, better.